# Return View encoded in UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: xml, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2, itunes, atom-feed

In my MVC Web Application, I developed a function to return a Newsstand Atom Feed (for Apple's Newsstand).
One of their requirements for this feed is that it is effectively encoded in UTF-8 and must not include a BOM.
This is how I coded my view (class names are fictional to preserve my company's privacy):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable (Of AtomFeed))" ContentType="application/atom+xml" ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:news="http://itunes.apple.com/2011/Newsstand"><%="" %><%  If Not Model Is Nothing Then%><%  Dim updateDate As String = ViewData("feedUpdate")%><% If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(updateDate)) Then%>
<updated><%= updateDate %></updated><%
End If%><% For Each f In Model%>
<entry>
    <id><%= f.id%></id>
    <updated><%= f.updated%></updated>
    <published><%= f.published%></published>
    <news:end_date><%= f.endDate%></news:end_date>
    <summary><%= f.summaryText%></summary>
    <news:cover_art_icons>
        <news:cover_art_icon size="SOURCE" src="<%= f.newspaperCover %>"/>
    </news:cover_art_icons>
</entry><%
        Next%><%
End If%>
</feed>
```

Today we received a mail from itunes complaining that they couldn't import our XML, without a clue as to why it failed.
The rendered XML is compliant to their requirements so my only guess is that there is a problem with the encoding of my view.

How do I correctly return this view in UTF-8 without BOM, so that when they pull the XML from my given url, it will be processed correctly?

EDIT:

After using Darin's implementation, I ended up with the following feed

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns:news="http://itunes.apple.com/2011/Newsstand"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text"></title>
  <id>uuid:5fc48c36-a1d3-4280-a856-a1a0528e2552;id=1</id>
  <updated>2012-07-23T00:40:00Z</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>23.07.2012</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <summary type="text">...</summary>
    <updated>2012-07-23T00:40:00Z</updated>
    <published xmlns="">2012-07-23T00:40:00Z</published>
    <news:end_date>2012-07-24T00:40:00Z</news:end_date>
    <news:cover_art_icons>
      <news:cover_art_icon size="SOURCE"
      src="https://www.someurl.com" />
    </news:cover_art_icons>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>22.07.2012</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <summary type="text">...</summary>
    <updated>2012-07-22T00:40:00Z</updated>
    <published xmlns="">2012-07-22T00:40:00Z</published>
    <news:end_date>2012-07-23T00:40:00Z</news:end_date>
    <news:cover_art_icons>
      <news:cover_art_icon size="SOURCE"
      src="https://www.someurl.com" />
    </news:cover_art_icons>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Now Apple's Newsstand cannot import the following feed because they say they can't find element  in this feed's entry element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating the an XML feed manually in a view I would recommend you using the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class which is designed for that purpose.

So let's assume that you have some domain model representing your data:

```
public class NewsstandFeed
{
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AtomFeed> Items { get; set; }
}

public class AtomFeed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string SummaryText { get; set; }
    public string NewspaperCover { get; set; }
}
```

and then a controller that will query some DAL to retrieve the domain model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Normally this will come from a database or something,
        // but I am hardcoding it for demonstration purposes here
        var model = new NewsstandFeed
        {
            Updated = DateTime.Now,
            Items = new[]
            {
                new AtomFeed 
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Updated = DateTime.Now,
                    Published = DateTime.Now,
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                    SummaryText = "some summary",
                    NewspaperCover = "http://www.google.com"
                }
            }
        };

        return new NewsstandFeedResult(model);
    }
}
```

Notice the `NewsstandFeedResult` that the controller action returns? Let's implement it:

```
public class NewsstandFeedResult : ActionResult
{
    public const string NewsstandNS = "http://itunes.apple.com/2011/Newsstand";
    public NewsstandFeed Model { get; private set; }

    public NewsstandFeedResult(NewsstandFeed model)
    {
        Model = model;
        if (model.Items == null)
        {
            model.Items = Enumerable.Empty<AtomFeed>();
        }
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";

        var feed = new SyndicationFeed();
        var n = new XmlQualifiedName("news", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
        XNamespace newsstandNs = NewsstandNS;
        feed.AttributeExtensions.Add(n, newsstandNs.ToString());
        if (Model.Updated.HasValue)
        {
            feed.LastUpdatedTime = new DateTimeOffset(Model.Updated.Value.ToUniversalTime());
        }

        var items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            var si = new SyndicationItem();
            si.Id = item.Id.ToString();
            si.LastUpdatedTime = new DateTimeOffset(item.Updated.ToUniversalTime());
            si.Summary = new TextSyndicationContent(item.SummaryText);

            si.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement(newsstandNs + "end_date", item.EndDate.ToUniversalTime()));
            si.ElementExtensions.Add(
                new XElement(
                    newsstandNs + "cover_art_icons",
                    new XElement(
                        newsstandNs + "cover_art_icon", 
                        new XAttribute("size", "SOURCE"), 
                        new XAttribute("src", item.NewspaperCover)
                    )
                )
            );
            items.Add(si);
        }
        feed.Items = items;

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(response.OutputStream))
        {
            var formatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter(feed);
            formatter.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. Now simply navigate to `/home/index` and you will get a valid Atom feed respecting all industry standards so that you don't have to worry about BOMs and stuff.

Comment: I appreciate the fact you took your time to explain this to me, and it will come in handy in the future, but with all due respect, you didn't need to be rude about it at the beginning of your answer. Besides that, you didn't answer my question at all, because I asked specifically how to return that View as it is now in UTF-8 format without BOM. I'm thankful for this example you coded here but I'd really appreciate if you could answer my original question, without criticizing its content.

Comment: Sorry, I think that what you are trying to achieve initially is wrong. That's my opinion and engaging only myself. So that's why I offered a better alternative. Remember that Stack Overflow is not just about answering questions. It's a well referenced site where many people come to look for solutions to problems and I don't want them to be doing the same error as you. Feel completely free to downvote and ignore my answer if it doesn't help you. You could always hope that someone else will answer your original question. And I apologize if my answer was rude to you.

Comment: Offering better solutions is fine, but being rude about it is not. Like I said, I do appreciate what you've shown me, and I never said that my version is better than yours, or claimed that it's right. But I'd appreciate if you could tell me how to return that View page in UTF-8 format without a BOM.

Comment: Once again I apologize. I will update my answer to remove the part where I was rude with you.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I consider your approach good (once again, I never said it wasn't) but I will wait until someone will teach me how I can encode the View in UTF-8 without the BOM part. Thanks for shedding your knowledge.

Comment: I tried to implement your example but it blows up @ si.ElementExtensions.Add(New XElement(NewsstandNS + "end_date", item.endDate)).
I have my date formatted like so:"2012-07-20T00:40:00Z"
The error says "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."
That is a format required by Apple. Any way around this?

Comment: What's the `NewsstandNS` variable in your example? I suspect that it is a string. It shouldn't be. Look at my example more closely. The variable I am passing there is of type `XNamespace` which is assignable from a string.

Comment: You're right Darin, so it's already fixed. The feed was generated without major problems. Now the only problem that it has is that it is inserting the tags <title> and <id> on the feed. I will edit my question to show you what I mean.

Comment: I know what you mean. You don't need to update your question. Those tags are part of the atom standard. They shouldn't interfere. You should not remove them. Otherwise you would be generating invalid atom feed. They might not be required by Apple but this doesn't mean that they shouldn't be present.

Comment: As it says in their documentation pdf: "The Newsstand Atom Feed is based on the Atom 1.0 format". Are you sure including these extra tags won't mess up the processing of this feed? I'm sorry for being stubborn about it (though I have accepted your way as best) but I don't want to run into the risk of them sending us another email claiming they couldn't import our feed.
And another problem is with the dates format, since it's using a datetimeoffset it doesn't render like "2012-07-19T00:40:00Z". Can you help me with this issue, please?

Comment: I assure you that those 2 attributes are required as per the [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt). Checkout the [XSD](http://www.kbcafe.com/rss/atom.xsd.xml) as well. Don't hesitate to read it if you don't believe me. And honestly, would you expect the SyndicationFeed class that's built into .NET to produce an invalid Atom feed?

Comment: Please look at the edit of my above comment. I also need help with the date formats which they require in the format I've shown above.

Comment: Which date more specifically?

Comment: Alright, just call `.ToUniversalTime()` on all the dates that you are passing to the `DateTimeOffset` constructor as well as your `end_date`. I will update my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Darin, thanks a lot for your patience even upon my stubbornness. I really appreciate the lesson and admit to being wrong about not wanting to follow your approach at first. Another lesson learned, thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to bother you again but I have a question I hope you can help me with. Still regarding this Feed you helped me build, it isn't being imported by Apple's Newsstand. They say they cannot read the tag <published>. I'm going to update my question with the current xml I give them